# Why does ng test cause my computer to freak out?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tried to test that a simple Angular project was running properly; when I run ng test, this is what happens and I have no idea how to fix it:

[image]

Comment: Are you probably affected by this? https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/dev-corrupts-npm-libs-colors-and-faker-breaking-thousands-of-apps/

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know about that. Thank you for sharing!